# Extract first three elements from an URL with a Regular expression

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

Given the following URL:

```
http://www.example.com/path1/path2/page
```

Is there a simple way to extract the first three blocks of it with a regular expression, that is:

```
http://www.example.com/path1/path2
```

I've found some examples how to do it with some coding (perl/javascript) however I'd really appreciate if somebody pointed me to a sed/awk example which uses a regular expression to do it.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Solution 1st:*** With simple parameter expansion.

```
echo "${val%/*}"
```

***Solution 2nd:*** with `awk`.

```
echo "$val"  | awk 'match($0,/.*\//){print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH-1)}'
```

***Solution 3rd:*** With one more `awk`.

```
 echo "$val" | awk -F"/" 'NF--;1'  OFS="/"
```

***Solution 4th:*** With `sed`.

```
echo "$val" | sed 's/\(.*\/\).*/\1/;s/\/$//'
```

Comment: As I will need to insert them in a loop the solutions 2,3 and 4 are perfect. I've tested them all. They all work, except that the Solution 3 returns 2 occurrences for the URL.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Carla, glad that it helped you, cheers keep learning and keep sharing.

Answer (score 1):

*to extract the first three blocks* (as opposed to for example remove last block) *of it with a regular expression* using Bash regex:

```
$ [[ "$var" =~ ^(https?://)?([^/]+/){0,3} ]] && echo $BASH_REMATCH
http://www.example.com/path1/path2/
```

Explained:

- `^(https?://)?` Don't worry about that
- `([^/]+/){0,3}` 0 to 3 blocks matched to output

It supports for example:

```
$ var=https://www.example.com/path1/path2/page
https://www.example.com/path1/path2/

$ var=www.example.com/path1/path2/page
www.example.com/path1/path2/

$ var=www.example.com/path1/
www.example.com/path1/
```